# array map and populate the result based on object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a function

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])     

const addTask = (title, role) => {
        const newTasks = [...tasks, { title, role}]
        setTasks(newTasks)
}
```

every form is submitted, addTask function is create state data containing an array of objects

```
[
{title: "make a coffee", role: "employee"},
{title: "react the sales target", role: "salesman"},
{title: "clean the room", role: "employee"},
{title: "call the client", role: "boss"},
]
```

i want to populate task based on role

```
const TaskList = ({ tasks }) => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
                {tasks.map((task, index) =>
                        <Col sm="12" md="4">
                            <h4 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                                {task.role} 
                            </h4>
                            <TaskCard task={task} index={index} />
                        </Col>
                )}
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}

const TaskCard = ({ task, index, completeTask, editTask, removeTask }) => {
    return (
        <Container className="mb-3">
            <Card body inverse color={task.completed ? 'success' : 'danger'}>
                <CardText>{task.title}</CardText>
                <p></p>
                <div className="Card-btn">
                    <i className="fas fa-check-circle fa-2x fa-fw" onClick={() => completeTask(index)}></i>
                    <i className="fas fa-pen fa-2x fa-fw" onClick={() => editTask(index)}></i>
                    <i className="fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x fa-fw" onClick={() => removeTask(index)}></i>
                </div>
            </Card>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

but instead of create a task list column for each role, its create new role card
[image]

how to populate task in column based by role? should i filter it first?

Comment: That is obvious because your `<TaskCard task={task} index={index} />` is inside the `map()`

Comment: Are you attempting to fill in the tasks on the card?

Comment: @EdisonPebojot i do, what i want is grouping tasks by role, if new task have same role, its create a new card below in same column

Comment: @anggapw Please take a look at my answer below, it should help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need modify your task array a bit. You need group the data by role. And for this purpose I would recommend using a `Map`.

```
const tasks = [
  { title: 'make a coffee', role: 'employee' },
  { title: 'react the sales target', role: 'salesman' },
  { title: 'clean the room', role: 'employee' },
  { title: 'call the client', role: 'boss' },
];

const m = new Map();

for (const task of tasks) {
  const {role, title} = task;
  if (m.has(role)) {
    const temp = m.get(role);
    m.set(role, [...temp, title]) 
  }else {
    m.set(role, [title])
  }
}

console.log(m);
```

Now you can loop over the map and for every role there would be an array of tasks which you can again loop over to create Task cards.

Take a look at the following code snippet:

```js
const tasks = [
  { title: "make a coffee", role: "employee" },
  { title: "react the sales target", role: "salesman" },
  { title: "clean the room", role: "employee" },
  { title: "call the client", role: "boss" },
];

function App() {
  const renderItems = () => {
    const m = new Map();
    for (const task of tasks) {
      const { role, title } = task;
      if (m.has(role)) {
        const temp = m.get(role);
        m.set(role, [...temp, title]);
      } else {
        m.set(role, [title]);
      }
    }

    const renderArr = [];
    for (let item of m) {
      renderArr.push(<TaskList role={item[0]} />);
      for (let it of item[1]) {
        renderArr.push(<TaskCard task={it} />);
      }
    }
    return renderArr;
  };

  return renderItems();
}

const TaskList = ({ role }) => <h1>{role}</h1>;

const TaskCard = ({ task }) => <p>{task}</p>;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use loadash to group the array by `role` then iterate over role's and then iterate over each roles jobs , you'll have to modify my code to fit your `col` and `row` syntax .

```
import _ from 'lodash';

const TaskList = ({ tasks }) => {
    return (
        <Container>
 const groupedByRole = _.chain(tasks).groupBy("role").map((value, key) => ({ role: key, jobs: value }))
  .value()
  return (
    <div >
       {
         groupedByRole.map((role,index)=><div key={index} >
               <h4 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}> {role.role}  </h4>
                {
                  role.jobs.map((job,index)=><TaskCard key={index}  task={job.title} index={index} />)
                }
           </div>)
       }
    </div>
       </Container>
    )
}
```